# Zero-channel RAID for High Performance MySQL Server (IBM ServeRAID 8k) : Any Experience/Recommendation?

Tags: hardware-raid, raid10, ibm

We are getting this IBM rack mount server and it has this IBM ServeRAID8k storage controller with Zero-Channel RAID and 256MB battery backed cache. It can support RAID 10 which we need for our high performance MySQL server which will have 4 x 15000K RPM 300GB SAS HDD. This is mission-critical and we want as much bandwidth and performance. Is this a good card or should we replace with another IBM RAID card?

IBM ServeRAID 8k SAS Controller option provides 256 MB of battery backed 533 MHz DDR2 standard power memory in a fixed mounting arrangement. The device attaches directly to IBM planar which can provide full RAID capability.

```
Manufacturer    IBM
Manufacturer Part # 25R8064
Cost Central Item # 10025907
Product Description IBM ServeRAID 8k SAS - Storage controller (zero-channel RAID) - RAID 0, 1, 5, 6, 10, 1E
Device Type Storage controller (zero-channel RAID) - plug-in module
Buffer Size 256 MB
Supported Devices   Disk array (RAID)
Max Storage Devices Qty 8
RAID Level  RAID 0, RAID 1, RAID 5, RAID 6, RAID 10, RAID 1E
Manufacturer Warranty   1 year warranty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pretty old part and it doesn't perform extremely well. You might want to take a look at the Adaptec 5405Z which is a pretty high performance controller with no BBU required.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will look into that Adaptec 5405Z.